# UIAlertView with UITextField is being delayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uialertview

I'm trying to run [this example](http://hayageek.com/uialertview-example-ios/). But the alert view with text field is being delayed before showing up and it freezes the UI so that I cannot perform anything. Why is that happening? Normal `UIAlertView` without text fields work fine but only when adding text fields it hangs for few seconds before showing.

I also tried running this code in a clean project without any other codes just one button and still same problem:

```
- (IBAction)btn:(id)sender {
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                    message:@"Message"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Done"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [alert show];   
}
```

I'm running on iOS 8.4.

Comment: I think you have other operations that block the main thread.

Comment: @LucasHuang I don't have anything like I said it is a clean project I just added one button that runs the UIAlertView

Comment: If that's a clean project, that might be a bug and you can report to Apple.

Comment: can you make a small video of the problem?

Comment: So you're using no other code such as `dispatch_queues`? Are you running this on a simulator?

Comment: It's not the solution but notice that UIAlertView is deprecated on iOS8. Use UIAlertController instead: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/

Comment: @somtingwong no I'm running on my iPad

Comment: @seeya I have also tried UIAlertController but still the same